# Android: Exception using Closeable interface with Socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, interface

When I try to close a socket through its Closeable interface, I get an exception:

```
new java.net.Socket().close();
// no error

((java.io.Closeable) new java.net.Socket()).close();
// Throws: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: interface not implemented
```

Why is that?
The problem is only on Android devices, not on Java programs running on desktop.

Answer (score 13):

To quote Android [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62909):

> Socket
>   implements Closeable only since API level 19 (kitkat) but
>   that information isn't in the generated documentation.

Comment: This is a bad lack on the Android documentation... they should find a way to indicate that an interface is implemented (or a class is extended) only since a defined API level. However, thanks :)