# why a Socket is not instanceof Closeable at runtime?

Tags: java, android

In an Android app, I added this code to *onCreate()*

```
    Closeable sss = new Socket();
    if (!(sss instanceof Closeable)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Something unexpected happened");
    }
```

The imports are:

```
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.net.Socket;
```

The code compiles, but
I am getting the exception:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 8293): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity...: java.lang.RuntimeException: Something unexpected happened
...
E/AndroidRuntime( 8293): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Something unexpected happened
...
```

In a different context, the glitch causes a `java.lang.ArrayStoreException` (namely, *java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.net.Socket cannot be stored in an array of type java.io.Closeable[]*).

Am I missing something?
Any idea what to do?

**EDIT**
Similarly, when `DatagramSocket` is used as `MyClass<DatagramSocket>` for `MyClass<T extends Closeable>`, it causes *java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: interface not implemented*.

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code here or retype it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353474/android-exception-using-closeable-interface-with-socket

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue occurs on Android API levels prior to 19. On affected versions, Socket does not implement Closeable.

Sources:

- [Android: Exception using Closeable interface with Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21353474/android-exception-using-closeable-interface-with-socket)
- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62909

Comment: But it does implement _close()_ on any API version, isn't it?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Answer (score 3):

Socket is not itself closeable, but both of its streams are. And closing either stream will close the Socket

Comment: How could I assign it to `Closeable sss` if it's not `Closeable`?

Comment: According to the docs it implements Closeable. However, as mentioned in the link I posted in my other comment "Socket implements Closeable only since API level 19 (kitkat) but that information isn't in the generated documentation."

Comment: @cygery Why does the instanceOf check fail?

Comment: I guess because OP is running the code on API level < 19. Is that correct @18446744073709551615?

Comment: android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT=16

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, I want to clarify something that was assumed to be evident by everyone in this discussion:

*How could I assign `Closeable sss = new Socket();` if `Socket` is not `Closeable`?*

The API requirements specified in AndroidManifest.xml are:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

and the device reports

```
android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT=16
```

The code was compiled for API level 19, this is why it was successfully compiled. But it was run on API level 16, and this is why it failed.

In other words, the compile-time check was performed for API19 on one computer (the desktop PC) while the run-time check was performed for API16 on another computer (the handheld device).